# Slow speed crunch/pop sound?

Tags: brakes, noise, suspension, wheels

Having this issue that started recently. Hearing and feeling in the steering wheel and pedals crunch/pop sound when rolling slowly.

- On/off brakes doesn't seem to matter.
- In gear/off gear doesn't matter.
- Idling or fully turned off doesn't matter.
- Happens only when driving slowly.
- Tried removing wheels, tightened the lugnuts.
- Forward or backwards doesn't matter.
- Seems to happen when rolling downhill more often.
- Checked all wheel bearing - seems to be in good shape.
- Lifted front wheels and with handbrake spun the front today by hands, no sound, but they were spinning in opposite direction, so I suspect only transfer case was involved.

Car details:
- Stock rotors at 86k miles, so replacing soon because there is quite a lip there.
- Pads at 60% just cleaned all of them today.

Initially suspected brakes, but that should go away when you get on/off brakes.

Now I am not even sure - is it diff pins? Transfer case? I can't make a video at the moment because I can feel it more than hear, so cellphone doesn't pick it up along with other noises in car.

If I was to describe, feels like when you drive over gravel and some rocks shoot out from under your wheel under the weight of the car... not rhythmic sound, more of random number of beats per second.

**How do I diagnose what is aside from what I tried already?
What can it be?**

Vehicle: 2012 Mitsubish Evolution X

This video shows the noise in the last 7 seconds. You will hear a few distinct POPs, similar to when you drive over snow and it compacts. USE GOOD SPEAKERS OR HEADPHONE, otherwise they are hard to hear.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nkmJ1KgnpQ

Comment: Did you check to see if there are rocks embedded into the tire tread?

Comment: I'd still be leaning towards wheel bearings. How did you check them?

Comment: Record the sound and upload it somewhere....

Comment: You sure you did not run over a bag of Cheetos? ;-)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes, but sound is not like rocks at all.

Comment: @Pete I lifted the car up and wiggled the wheels by grabbing on 9 and 3 and then 12 and 6. No movement what so ever. Also spun the wheels in the air.

Comment: @Moab No :) That would be something I would never let go if I did it :D

Comment: Try holding on the the spring and spinning the wheel if you feel any vibration on the spring the bearing is bad.

Comment: @Ben That is an interesting way of doing it. I will definitely try it, but would that be affected by brake pads slightly rubbing on the brake disk or the bearing would overpower that?

Comment: the brakes would have to be metal to metal before you'd feel it that way.

Comment: @Ben unless there is a significant lip where brake pad would catch on, no?

Comment: can you post a picture? if your brakes are so low that the steel part of the pad is touching the rotor maybe thats where you should start.

Comment: @Ben Pads are at 60% of their thickness, and the metal part doesn't touch, I was more thinking about the pad material itself touching, but in that case it will quickly become grooved and noise will go away I guess.

Comment: Have you recently had new tires put on?  I had this exact same thing happen to me after I had new tires installed, went back to the shop and told them I hear a noise at low speeds and they tried to tell my is was a cv axle.  I said they were crazy and there was no sign of that and this didnt happen tell they touched it.  Went to another location, we had the car raised bounced the passenger rear tear to examine where the noise was coming from and sure enough a metal piece had broken off the machine and made its way inside the tire.

Comment: Was it stuck in the tire or was it just bouncing inside?

Comment: @Alexus stuck in the tire

Comment: Interesting, this is the closes I can think of as a sound, but what are the chances. I guess if all else fails, I will go to tire shop. Have a few other places to check still :) Thanks!

Comment: @Alexus Did you ever figure out the issue with this one?

Comment: Yes, it was the wheel bearing. Shortly after it started to squeal and after replacement all issues went away.

Answer (score 3):

Ended up being left front wheel bearing. Shortly after the bearing started to squeal. After the replacement, all issues are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Empty and change your diff fluid, gearbox fluid and transfer case fluid.
When the fluids are out and in the pan, run a magnet through each to see if you can collect any metal pieces.

Being an evo, I'd be suspecting either diff or transfer case as the first thing to look at. When the teeth in the gears and clutch packs inside the diffs start to fail, they can roll around in there making all sorts of noises. As the rpm's increase, these pieces can end up more towards the outside of the case so it's less noticeable (until the moment of total failure).

If it where wheel bearings, you'd likely notice the noise at all rpm's I would have imagined.

Comment: Will do, sad though that I just changed fluids recently in all diffs.